# What's the difference between STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm somewhat confused as to what the difference is between STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in Django's `'staticfiles'` app.

I believe I understand what the `STATIC_ROOT` is: it's essentially the location on the server where the staticfiles' `collectstatic` command will place the static files collected from your django project. The `collectstatic` command searches in the locations that you specify in the `STATIC_FINDERS` setting.

However, what exactly does the `STATIC_URL` do? What should this be set to? Apparently it's intended to be set something such that users can access static files. But what is it's relationship with `STATIC_ROOT`?

Why is the default value of `STATIC_URL` simply `/static/` ? Does `STATIC_URL` have to be able to reference `STATIC_ROOT`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like you mentioned, it is pretty clear from the documentation:

> **STATIC_ROOT:**
>
> The absolute path to the directory where `collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment.
>
> **STATIC_URL**
>
> default: None
>
> URL to use when referring to static files located in `STATIC_ROOT`.
>
> Example: `"/static/"` or `"http://static.example.com/"`

While, the `STATIC_ROOT` is just the path to the directory where static files have been collected, `STATIC_URL` is the URL which will serve those static files.

And, as you can see in the example, you can define `STATIC_URL` as a subdomain `"http://static.example.com/"` and when you use it in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/base.css" type="text/css" />
```

It will be treated as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.example.com/css/base.css" type="text/css" />
```

But, if the `STATIC_URL` was just `/static/` then the above link would point to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css" type="text/css" />
```

And, since this `href` starts with `/` it will append your domain to access the static files:  `http://yourdomain/static/css/base/css`

---

> Why is the default value of `STATIC_URL` simply `/static/` ? Does STATIC_URL have to be able to reference `STATIC_ROOT`?

Default value of `STATIC_URL` is not `/static/` but None as you can see in the documentation. And, it doesn't have to reference to `STATIC_ROOT` because it is not dependent on it (as shown in the example above).

Comment: Great answer. I have to add, that the use of {{STATIC_URL}} inside a template is not recommended. Use {% load static %} ... {% static 'css/main.css' %} instead. http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/stop-using-static-url-in-templates/

Comment: But as I just tried and found out that I can set `STATIC_URL = '/static/abcd/'`, basically just an arbitrary path and Django still correctly fetches static files. For example, it is serving a CSS file from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/abcd/css/app.css" type="text/css">` as seen in the DevTools although there is no such directory on my system. My CSS file is in  `common_static/css/app.css` and is collected to `static/css/app.css`. So this threw a really big wrench into my understanding of how `STATIC_URL` works. How is this possible?

Comment: @ruslaniv I have the same doubt. Have you found the answer to it?

Comment: @Navdeep No, not yet, unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

[`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) is simply the prefix or url that is prepended to your static files and is used by the `static` method in Django templates mostly. For more info, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/).

[`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) is the directory or location where your static files are deployed when you run `collectstatic`.

So, when you have `STATIC_URL` defined as `/static/`, then your users would request static files from `/static/file-name.example` (a relative URL on your server).

If you had customized your `collectstatic` to deploy static files to another server, you could set `STATIC_URL` to `https://static.example.org/`.

Then, you'd access your files at `https://static.example.org/filename.ext`.

Another example I have is using the Boto S3 library to upload static and media content to Amazon S3. My `STATIC_URL` looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, STATIC_S3_PATH)
```

It constructs a static URL prefix like this `//mycloudfront.whatever/static/` so users will be served files from our CDN.

My `STATIC_ROOT` however is defined as:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/%s/' % STATIC_S3_PATH
```

...because I need to upload my content to Amazon S3 and **not** Cloudfront.

Answer (score 4):

`STATIC_ROOT` is where all your assets will be collected by the `collectstatic` command. The contents of this directly contain all static assets from all applications listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` (from their own `static` folders) and any file locations mentioned in [`STATICFILE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs).

Once you have collected all these assets, in order for django to create urls you need to tell it what is the base URL to these assets, that's the `STATIC_URL` setting, and it must always end in a slash.

Comment: Would you mind looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716200/whats-the-difference-between-static-url-and-static-root-in-django?rq=1#comment117311502_37717024 ?