# Why isn't django serving my SPA static files correctly?

Tags: python, django, npm, single-page-application, yarnpkg

I'm building a website using a [Django backend](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Vuejs frontend](https://vuejs.org/). In development I started the backend and the frontend separately with `python manage.py runserver` and `yarn serve` respectively. This worked great and I now want to deploy the website. To do this I ran `yarn build`, which created a `dist/` folder in my frontend folder. So my structure was like this:

```
cockpit
├── backend/
│   ├── cockpit/
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   ├── css/
│   │   └── etc..
│   ├── settings/
│   │   └── settings.py
│   └── manage.py
└── frontend/
    └── dist/
        ├── index.html
        ├── css/
        └── js/
```

I now want to serve the sources in `frontend/dist/` from my django project so that I can run everything using uwsgi. To do this I'm trying to follow [this description](https://medium.com/zenithec-techware/serve-spa-with-django-1f492f2857ed). I have the following `settings/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cockpit/', include("cockpit.urls")),
    re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

and set the following settings in my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['static'],  # <== ADDED THIS
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # removed to keep this example small
        },
    },
]
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/dist'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

print("BASE_DIR:", BASE_DIR)
print("STATIC_ROOT:", STATIC_ROOT)
print("STATICFILES_DIRS:", STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

And the prints show me this:

```
BASE_DIR: /home/kramer65/repos/cockpit/backend
STATIC_ROOT: /home/kramer65/repos/cockpit/backend/static/
STATICFILES_DIRS: ['/home/kramer65/repos/cockpit/backend/../frontend/dist']
```

Then I ran `python manage.py collectstatic:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic

150 static files copied to '/home/kramer65/repos/cockpit/backend/static'.
```

So it now looks like this:

```
cockpit
├── backend/
│   ├── cockpit/
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   ├── css/
│   │   └── etc..
│   ├── settings/
│   │   └── settings.py
│   └── manage.py
│   └── static/
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── css/
│       └── js/
└── frontend/
    └── dist/
        ├── index.html
        ├── css/
        └── js/
```

I tested it by running the (node) `http-server` from the `backend/static/` folder. In the browser the website loads and runs perfect. Below is the output from the command line:

```
$ http-server
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://192.168.0.104:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[2020-05-18T13:50:58.487Z]  "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
(node:5928) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
[2020-05-18T13:50:58.671Z]  "GET /css/chunk-vendors.2c7f3eba.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
[2020-05-18T13:50:58.679Z]  "GET /css/app.e15f06d0.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
[2020-05-18T13:50:58.681Z]  "GET /js/chunk-vendors.9c409057.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
[2020-05-18T13:50:58.687Z]  "GET /js/app.c930fce5.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
```

I stopped this `http-server`, started the Django dev server and opened the browser. The terminal shows me this:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 18, 2020 - 17:57:00
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'settings.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.4.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
HTTP GET / 200 [0.22, 127.0.0.1:33224]
HTTP GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.css 200 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:33232]
HTTP GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css 200 [0.05, 127.0.0.1:33234]
HTTP GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js 200 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:33232]
HTTP GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.timer.js 200 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:33234]
HTTP GET /js/chunk-vendors.9c409057.js 200 [0.80, 127.0.0.1:33228]
HTTP GET /css/chunk-vendors.2c7f3eba.css 200 [0.94, 127.0.0.1:33224]
HTTP GET /js/app.c930fce5.js 200 [0.98, 127.0.0.1:33230]
HTTP GET /css/app.e15f06d0.css 200 [0.99, 127.0.0.1:33226]
HTTP GET /favicon.ico 200 [0.09, 127.0.0.1:33226]
```

In the browser console I see the sources seem to be loaded, but some seem to be empty (0 bytes) and the screen doesn't show anything. Below is a screenshot of the results and a screenshot of the Static Files tab in the Django Debug Bar.

Why isn't it serving those files correctly in Django?

[image]

[image]

### Edit

I just found that if I change

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

to

```
STATIC_URL = '/'
```

it works correctly when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html`, but now `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` gives me this error:

[image]

[EDIT 2]

Ok, so following the advice of @geek_life I changed the values in my settings file to:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_NAME = 'cockpit'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, PROJECT_NAME, "static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/dist')]
print("## BASE_DIR:", BASE_DIR)
print("## STATIC_ROOT:", STATIC_ROOT)
print("## STATICFILES_DIRS:", STATICFILES_DIRS)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['cockpit/static/'],  # <= THIS IS WHAT I CHANGED
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {}  # And here some options
    },
]
```

Which prints out

```
## BASE_DIR: /home/kramer65/repos/cockpit/backend
## STATIC_ROOT: /home/kramer65/repos/cockpit/backend/cockpit/static/
## STATICFILES_DIRS: ['/home/kramer65/repos/cockpit/backend/../frontend/dist']
```

And in the file `settings/urls.py` I (still) got this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cockpit/', include("cockpit.urls")),
    re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

I then copied the `static/` folder with the built vuejs-ap from `cockpit/backend/` to `cockpit/backend/cockpit/`.

Unfortunately I still get the same result. The index.html loads, but the JSS and CSS files still don't. What can I try next?

Comment: I think the last part of your question is happening because of your url path. It is able to find `index.html` in the static files so it is working when you go to that directly... try this: `re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"))`

Comment: @kramer65 did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4):

### Cause of errors

For the first case

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Django tries to look for static files in the `backend/static/` folder only in the case where anything with url with `/static/` i.e. for e.g. `/static/css/*` or `/static/js/*` is mentioned in your `index.html`, but that is not the case here `index.html` has file references like `/css/*` and `/js/*`, hence they are not found.

The reason this case works in the blog example is due to the same reason i.e. their template files are kept under a `'../frontend/build` directory and static files are in '../frontend/build/static' hence the `index.html` will look for `static/js/*` instead of a `/js/*` hence `/static/` url location is accessed in Django, which then looks for the files in `backend/static` correctly

This is why, in your code, setting it to second case i.e.

```py
STATIC_URL = '/'
```

gets the urls for static files correctly to `/css/*` and `/js/*` and even your `/index.html` can be thought of as a static file i.e. all these urls are considered static and are searched in the `backend/static/` folder and hence appearing correctly in the browser.

But now the URLs are messed up i.e. this:

```py
re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

can be treated as Django looking for this location: `/`, but it is already reserved for searching static files and not including any file name after `/` means you are not looking for any file.

### Possible Solution

Django allows custom url patterns i.e. you can create 2 new variables in settings.py i.e.

```py
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATIC_JS_URL = "/js/"
STATIC_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "js/")

STATIC_CSS_URL = "/css/"
STATIC_CSS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "css/")
```

and then configure your urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cockpit/', include("cockpit.urls")),
    re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_JS_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_JS_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_CSS_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_CSS_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use of `STATIC_URL`

First of all, `STATIC_URL` will be the url where the static files [will be served](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37717024/10028980). So if you set `STATIC_URL='/'` and then navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html` it will essentially serve the `index.html` from within the static folder of your Django application. If you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` you're at your 'static folder root', and as you can see, a directory index is forbidden. So don't use `STATIC_URL='/'`

### Location of the files

The tutorial you followed adds the build folder of the SPA to the templates in your Django `settings.py` file.

So you should try and add:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'frontend', 'dist')],  # <== ADDED THIS
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # removed to keep this example small
        },
]
```

or if you want to point to your static files as template directory:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')], 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # removed to keep this example small
        },
]
```

However I don't think it is best practice since static files (images, JS, CSS) have their own qualification in [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/).

### Note on `os.path`

Also, for your `STATICFILES_DIRS`, that's not how `os.path.join()` [works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). The first argument should be a path you want to join with one or more path components, the components are then passed as the next arguments. Furthermore, `BASE_DIR`is not at the right directorylevel, as you can see when you printed out the `BASE_DIR` path. You need the parent of the `BASE_DIR`directory. To get the path of the [parent directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname), you can do `os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)`, because `BASE_DIR` is a path. So applying this we get:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), frontend, dist),
]
```

### Final note

I do feel that it might be an anti pattern to have your SPA served by Django without it being completely self contained in the Django `BASE_DIR` (hence the name, base directory). But I don't know the source for it, or exactly how best practice this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a long time ago and I solved it with a simple solution.
It's too simple.
As I see, your static folder is not in your app root and it's in wrong place.
Put it in your app root...because Django is looking for the static folder inside the main root of your app, where views.py is in there.
Maybe you have 5 apps or more.
Django doesn't care about the number of apps you have, Django only looks for your static folder in your app root.
But your templates folder can be in your project root. 
So , put your static folder in your app root.
In this case I mean inside cockpit root.

And then you have to add this changes in settings.py

```
PROJECT_NAME = '---Your projects name---'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, PROJECT_NAME, 'static/')

EXTERNAL_APPS = [

     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  ]
```

Good Luck.

Comment: I Think Its Solve the Problem

Comment: You are thinking in a djangoic way, however your suggestion adds another step to frontend building process. Since vuejs app is completely separated, the builded app resides in its directory. And what @kramer65 does with STATIC_DIRS is very reasonable for his case. If he does what you suggest he will be building vue app, copping it under django app’s static folder and run collect static. And yet his problem still unsolved 

Comment: I added some points in my answer and these tips worked for me, however, he must first try the method I suggested to see what happens finally @smail-taha-ayka

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I tried it but still no luck. I added a description of what I changed to the question. Maybe I'm missing something stupid?

Answer (score 0):

First things first! If you want to serve your UI from Django as static files for the production, it's a bad idea! You need to consider using nginx or similar web server to serve static files for you.

The `TemplateView` in your `urls.py` is a bit problematic. Since your static files are served under `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your first scenario, the urls for js and css files does not match. You might edit the files and put `static` template tags inside `index.hml` but it's not a good idea as well. When you do changes on vuejs side, you need to build and replace the package directly and your site is updated. So the this line needs to be deleted forever, index.html has to be treated as static file:

```
    re_path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

When you changed `STATIC_URL = '/'` you may access all of your static files. If you run django in `debug = True` it serves static files automatically. Otherwise you need to add static url conf to the file. (DO NOT FORGET, This is not good for production!)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cockpit/', include("cockpit.urls")),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

With this setup you need to be careful about your urls and static file namings. They might override each other.

P.S: Thank you for such a detailed question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just a question, why is serving my static files through Django a bad idea? I mean, I know nginx has caching and all that stuff. But this is a very low traffic site (maybe 100 views per day) so performance is not an issue. As far as I understand uwsgi is a perfectly fine server if it's a slow traffic personal website. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's all about performance. If you don't have high performance expectations, than it's OK.

Comment: Because every page yields several static files, that means several workers are going to be busy for one page view in addition to the page itself. Just one page view with 10 static files can tie you up completely. Even for one user that means delays. I'd say 2 people at the same time would already slow down a default gunicorn setup.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dumb way to fix this issue.

This issue is about that html built by VueJS will get js and css from path like these `/js/app.12312sd.js` and `/css/app.dsfeewj.css`.

[image: html built by vueJS]

Default setting of static file root path is `/static/`, so you only need to change each `/js/...` and `/css/...` in `index.html` manually or use `sed` or something else to replace them to `/static/js/.../` and `/static/css/.../`.

You cannot replace `STATIC_URL` to `/` because it the root url for your website.

After you edit it, it will look like this, and then server your django server it will work well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before building your frontend put the css/ and js/ in a directory named 'static' leaving the index.html as it is. Then when you run `yarn build` your directory structure would be as follows -

```
cockpit
├── backend/
│   ├── cockpit/
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   ├── css/
│   │   └── etc..
│   ├── settings/
│   │   └── settings.py
│   └── manage.py
└── frontend/
    └── dist/
        ├── static/
        │       ├── css/
        │       └── js/
        └── index.html
```

Setup your BASE_DIR and a FRONTEND_DIR to point towards 'cockpit/frontend/dist' for quick use later on.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
FRONTEND_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'frontend','dist')
```

Now either copy frontend static files to your backend directory as you did earlier -

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR,'static/'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

OR you could directly point your backend to serve from the built frontend directory instead of copying it again. (I somehow always do this)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR,'static/')
```

Include your built frontend directory in your template directories for django to be able to serve `index.html`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [FRONTEND_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # removed to keep this example small
        },
    },
]
```

Now run your server

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
$ python manage.py runserver
```

If later you decide on deploying this online you could do that easily using this configuration itself by setting Nginx to serve static files from your static directory.
Hope this helps :)

Clearing your confusion in your [EDIT]

STATIC_ROOT points to the directory on your system. STATIC_URL refers to the URL at which your static files that are present in your STATIC_ROOT would be accessed while using your website.

Let's say you have a file script.js in your directory as shown

```
cockpit
├── backend/
│   ├── cockpit/
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   ├── css/
│   │   └── etc..
│   ├── settings/
│   │   └── settings.py
│   └── manage.py
└── frontend/
    └── dist/
        ├── static/
        │       ├── css/
        │       └── js/
        │          └── script.js
        └── index.html
```

and you have set your STATIC_ROOT to point towards 'cockpit/frontend/dist/static/'.

Now if you set your STATIC_URL as 'static/' you would be able to access that script at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/script.js

Alternatively, if you set your STATIC_URL to 'xcsdf/' you would access your js file at http://127.0.0.1:8000/xcsdf/js/script.js