# Django created staticfiles folder rather than static folder

Tags: django, collectstatic

I do not know why Django created a folder named staticfiles rather than static as expected. That might be the reason why I got an error after running `python manage.py collectstatic`:

```
The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:...\\static'
```

My settings file included:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

I had already tried to change 'staticfiles' to 'static' in STATIC_ROOT, but no success.

Could anyone please explain why and how to create a folder name "static"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In production (DEBUG=False), you should to create it by hand and execute `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Try changing the url to `STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'`, and check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/37717024/10951070.  I've had some issues with this because I had a static folder in my root project as well as each of my app folders.  Oh, and keep the other two settings as you have them already in your question.

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Not sure why.  Two ideas.  One, use [findstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic), run `python manage.py findstatic [filename-of-a-static-file]` for a clue.  Second edit your question with your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

**I considered your static files are placed inside your app(s)**

Try removing `STATICFILES_DIRS` so the setting will be:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

...and try to re-run `python manage.py collectstatic`

- Here is how `collectstatic` works:

  - First it collect static files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` if any, if there is no `STATICFILES_DIRS` in settings it collects static files from each app
  - Then placed them to `STATIC_ROOT`, so if your static files are placed inside your app(s) better to remove `STATICFILES_DIRS`

If still there is an error share your project structure